# error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Player*, std::vector<Player> >’ to ‘int’ in return

Tags: c++

there is my echelleetserpent.hpp :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

#ifndef ECHELLE
#define ECHELLE

struct Player{
    int position;
    int n_step;
    Player(): position(0), n_step(0) {};
};

class SnakesAndLadders{
    private:
        int n_players;
        int n_board;
        std::vector<Player> players;
        std::vector<int> board;
    public:
        int roll_die(std::mt19937 &) const;
        bool one_step(std::mt19937 & G, int j);
        int game(std::mt19937);
};



#endif
```

And my echelleetserpent.cpp

```
#include "echelleetserpent.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

int SnakesAndLadders::roll_die(std::mt19937 & gen) const {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> U(1,6);
    int dice = U(gen);
    return dice;
}

bool SnakesAndLadders::one_step(std::mt19937 & G, int j) {
    int dice = roll_die(G);
    std::cout << "Le résultat du dé est : " << dice << std::endl;
    players[j].n_step++;
    players[j].position+=dice;
    return (players[j].position >= n_board) ? true : false;
}

int SnakesAndLadders::game(std::mt19937 G) {
    while (std::any_of(players.begin(), players.end(), [this](Player p) {return p.position < n_board;})) {
        for(int i=0; i<n_players; i++) {
            this->one_step(G,i);
        }
    }
    return std::min_element(players.begin(), players.end(), [this](Player p1, Player p2) {
        if(p1.position>=n_board and p2.position >= n_board) { return p1.position < p2.position; } else { return false; }});
}
```

And i get the following error :

> echelleetserpent.cpp:66:116: error: cannot convert
>   ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >’ to ‘int’
>   in initialization  n >= n_board) { return p1.position < p2.position; }
>   else { return false; }});

Comment: `std::min_element` returns an iterator to the smallest element in the range which is not convertible to the return type `int`.

Comment: What is `SnakesAndLadders::game` supposed to return? The index of some element?

Answer (score 0):

`std::min_element` will give you an **iterator** pointing to the min element (or to 'end' if the container is empty).

That's what the error says: `error: cannot convert '[..]normal_iterator' to 'int'`

What do you want to return? The index of the player, or the player itself? For the index:

```
  auto it = std::min_element(players.begin(),...// don't want to copy this
  if (it == players.end()) {
    return -1; // List was empty
  } else {
    return it - players.begin();
  }
```